# Stress-energy tensor of the EM field has zero trace

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, trace

The stress energy-tensor in EM is defined by
$$T^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\left(E^\mu_\rho E^{\nu\rho} - \frac{1}{4} g^{\mu\nu}E_{\rho\sigma}E^{\rho\sigma}\right)$$
I aim to show one of the properties presented on the WIKI page, namely that the trace is zero, we can write

$$g_{\mu \nu} T^{\mu \nu} = T^\mu_\mu =-\frac{1}{4\pi}\left(g_{\mu \nu}E^\mu_\rho E^{\nu\rho} - \frac{1}{4}g_{\mu \nu} g^{\mu\nu}E_{\rho\sigma}E^{\rho\sigma}\right)$$

I am not sure how to use tensorial properties to show that the result is zero, may I have a hint on how to proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: Hint 1: $E^\mu_\rho = g^{\mu \kappa} E_{\kappa\rho}$. 
Hint 2: $g_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\nu}=?$ in 4 dimensions.

Comment: $g_{\mu \nu}g^{\mu \nu} = 4$ in 4 dimensions. 

Then $T^\mu_\mu =-\frac{1}{4\pi}\left(g_{\mu \nu} g^{\mu \kappa} E_{\kappa \rho} E^{\nu\rho} - E_{\rho\sigma}E^{\rho\sigma}\right)$.

The first term seemingly gets more complicated, do i need to use another property of the sum over the $\mu$ on the metric tensors here?

Comment: Yes of course: the very basic property of metric tensor.

Comment: You should get rid of the metric tensors not put in more :-) .

Comment: I have gotten to the form $T_{\mu}^{\mu} = -\frac{1}{4\pi}(g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu \kappa} E_{\kappa \rho} E^{\nu \rho} - E_{\rho \sigma}E^{\rho \sigma})$ and have no idea how to proceed. I tried writing out the sum over $\mu$ on the first term but it just got messy very fast